# dmesg: custom time format

Tags: date, dmesg

`dmesg` has the option `-T` to print human-readable timestamps, and new versions have the option `--time-format`, where the time format can be changed, for instance:

```
--time-format iso
```

Unfortunately, the `iso` time format is not much readable either. Can I define my own time format using the standard `date` syntax? ie:

```
date +%F-%T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, e.g. by re-formatting the time with `gawk` (GNU `awk`) like this:

```
dmesg --time-format iso | gawk '{ printf (strftime("+%F-%T",mktime(gensub("[-+T:,]"," ","g",$1)))) ; $1 = ""; print $0}'
```

`dmesg` prints iso dates here like this:

```
2019-09-02T06:10:30,708864+02:00 this is an important message
```

We strip the first string of special characters then use the `mktime` function in (`g`)`awk` to parse the string into a date, then `strftime` to format - use your favourite parameters.

This gives something like

```
+2019-09-02-06:10:30 this is an important message
```

**Small notes:**

- We ignore the time zone here assuming this is obvious since we are running the command locally.
- Please note that the time given by `dmesg` can be inaccurate (in fact, sometimes way off) if you suspend and then wake the computer due to the way timestamps are stored, see `dmesg(1)`:

  ```
  man 1 dmesg
  ```

Comment: Ned64 - it did not work in `awk`, but it does work when I install `gawk`.

Comment: @MartinVegter OK, sorry, my `awk` *is* `gawk`. Will change it in the Answer just to be sure it runs on all systems!

Answer (score 3):

You can't, but you can parse `dmesg`-output:

```bash
dmesg --time-format iso \
| while read datestring rest; do \
  printf '%s\n' "$(date -d "$datestring" +%F-%T) $rest"; done
```

Comment: What exactly is the novelty over my earlier Answer? I suggest the same, only use a different formatting tool.

Comment: Didn't see yours before I posted.  `awk`likely is more performant than a while-loop,  but using date with a datestring will take care of the timezone, too.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I am an `awk`ward person.

Comment: I'm still trying to get a hang on `awk`.  It helps to see an `awk`-variant of everything I'm thinking of hereabouts :-)

Comment: Check out all my Answers here - 80% `awk` :-)